# Is there an "associative" symmetric "cryptographic" algorithm?

Tags: python, math, cryptography, bitwise-operators

In our application, we need an associative operation between two UUIDs.
For the other needs of the application, like non-commutativity (`A + B != B + A`) and reversibility (`(A + B) - B = A`), AES encoding/decoding is working fine as an operator, represented by signs `+`/`-` here, where `A` plays the role of a plaintext and `B` would be the `key`.

Since security is not the goal here, AES seems to be an overkill, besides the problem of non-associativity. Is there any kind of *associative* operation (bit-wise, integer arithmetic) that could replace AES, keeping its nice properties of *non-commutativity* and *reversibility*, and also keeping its (low) collision rate for different pairs `(A, B)`?

For clarity this the output of some operations with concrete values:

```
In [34]: from mypkg.mymodule.encoders import UUID                                                                                 

In [35]: a = UUID(b'asdasdasdasdasda'); a                                                                                     
Out[35]: cYÖe0Þót9jÞÖYILßjWÂ

In [36]: b = UUID(b'sdasdasdasdasdas'); b                                                                                     
Out[36]: jeÑaÐþOölÝRKÍHýzÐÓç

In [37]: c = UUID(b'dasdasdasdasdasd'); c                                                                                     
Out[37]: dp1pêÛçjWCsêäEhÜ8í5

In [38]: (a + b) + c                                                                                                          
Out[38]: ïfDdéÄÆæImúËöÓtzÊgø

In [39]: a + (b + c)                                                                                                          
Out[39]: lÏáÜIswæîÊá37ôrÔ4på

In [40]: (a + b) + c == a + (b + c)  # A `True` value is desired here.                                                        
Out[40]: False
```

Comment: The simplest thing I can think of is the group of 2x2 invertible matrices where the operation is matrix multiplication. Picking a suitable ring for the elements will depend on the range of unique values of the UUID.

Comment: Thanks Mr. President. I tried matrix multiplication, but it requires float to be invertible. The inverse matrix of `key` is needed for the operation to be reversible. The problem with float is that regarding lossy number precision/rounding.

Comment: Hence the statement about "picking a suitable ring ...". I would not choose the reals, I would choose a the integers mod p for a suitably large prime.